# Schedule an email to be sent

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, email, queue

Is there a way for me, with a WPF browser application, to schedule an email to be sent? What I will have is a date, date of user subscription, and then I would like it to send the user an email 5 days before their membership expires. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Who's responsible for actually sending the email?  The application itself or a server somewhere?

Comment: Well, in the end, this application is going to go on the web (it is a browser app). I don't think the application can do it, so it'd be a server, or some sort of database, but I honestly have no experience with this type of thing, so I need serious guidance

Comment: You could give [SQL Server notification services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171402(v=sql.90).aspx) a look.  Would save you the effort of implementing yet another scheduled email sender.

Comment: Ok. So, I have never used sql; so would I be able to use the mysql server thing provided by my webhost? would i just create a database in there?

Comment: You should be able to do some type of scheduling to fire off a task to send out an email once a day. Not sure what tools your host provides but I'm willing to bet they provide something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to write a record to a database table (say a email task table) then write a Windows service that polls this table say every minute, checks for any emails that need to be sent and then sends them.

Comment: right, but it's a browser application, that I will put on the web and it will be web only, can I still have a "Windows service" online?

Comment: What do you mean it's a browser application?  You mean a web site running on a server surely?  In which case unless you dont have access to the server then I dont see why you cant write a Windows service to send out the emails and then just install it on the server.

Comment: I guess it's like a website; visual studio just calls it a wpf browser application. Anyways, do I need to have a special host to do this?

Comment: here is a link from Microsoft on creating a Windows Service, there are plenty of articles out there if you google it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984464(v=vs.71).aspx.  You will need to have admin access to the server that you are installing the service on but technically the service can be installed on any server as long as it has access to the database where you are going to store records of which emails need to be sent.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be you'll have to do something on the server side with a scheduled job/task checking daily for who needs to get an email sent to them.

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of what I've been reading, but how exactly would I do this? Would you recommend using a sql table with sql jobs?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the SMTP server sends the emails immediately so you have to persist this queue in your application (or use MSMQ as queue storage) and have some part of your application executing the delivery at required time.

At this point my question is, if you can send when you know is the time to send, can't you send directly later without using the queue or do you have any logic in your application so that the email you would generate today can't be generated at later time?

I would probably create a Windows Service or, even better, have a scheduled task calling my application every day at midnight then the application verifies to whom the email should be sent right now, creates it and sends it out.